# Opencv + Python cv2.imwrite() and cv.imshow both images present different output

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am using Opencv(3.0) and Python 2.7 to do image processing, but I have an issue with `cv2.imwrite()` and `cv2.imshow()`. They produce different output,  my code is as below:

```
tfinal = (255)*(nir_img-red_img)/(nir_img+red_img)
cv2.imwrite(_db_img1+'_NDVI'+_ext_img,tfinal)
cv2.imshow('NDVI',tfinal)
```

First image is output of `cv2.imshow()`

[image: cv2_imshow_op]

Second image is output of `cv2.imwrite()`

[image: Cv2_imwrite_op]

Comment: What's the datatype of the elements of `tfinal` and what is the range of values stored in it? (min/max)

Comment: Hello Dan,
I'm using numpy using this syntax : print(tfinal.dtype) i have found that it is 'float64'.

Comment: Thank you @Martin for Edit my post. I'm Newbie at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen because of your data type. `imwrite` and `imshow` determine what to do with your data automatically, relaying on datatype. As said in documentation for [imwrite](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#imwrite) and [imshow](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#cv2.imshow):

`imwrite`:

> The function imwrite saves the image to the specified file. The image format is chosen based on the filename extension (see imread() for the list of extensions). Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function.

`imshow`:

> The function may scale the image, depending on its depth:
>
> - If the image is 8-bit unsigned, it is displayed as is.
> - If the image is 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit integer, the pixels are divided by 256.
>     That is, the value range [0,255*256] is mapped to [0,255].
> - If the
>     image is 32-bit floating-point, the pixel values are multiplied by
>
>   255. That is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to [0,255].

So, it seems that your underlying data type is not unsigned char, but float or 32-bit integer.

Also because of operation priorities you can run into troubles with:

`(255)*(nir_img-red_img)/(nir_img+red_img)`

You can run into overflow. It will be better to set values in range of [0; 1] and than multiply them:

`(255) * ( (nir_img-red_img)/(nir_img+red_img) )`

Comment: Hello Melnikov ,
thanks for your kind support .
I have found that tfinal data type  float64. as per your suggestion i have changed the syntax : (255) * ( (nir_img-red_img)/(nir_img+red_img) ).
but it is dispaly totally different image.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Melnikov Sergei for a brief introduction regarding mine solution.
I have resolved this using below syntax modified in my program.
when I am writing my image multiplied with 255 and I'm getting the same result.

```
tfinal = (255)*(nir_img-red_img)/(nir_img+red_img)
cv2.imwrite(_db_img1+'_NDVI'+_ext_img,tfinal*255)
cv2.imshow('NDVI',tfinal)
```